# Web Camera with Raspberry Pi3 to detect objects using Google Cloud Vision

Tags: python, camera, raspberry-pi, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

I want to integrate USB Web Camera with Raspberry Pi3 and send the images captured to Google Cloud Vision to detect objects. Any Python 3 library for doing the same?
I have successfully integrated my web camera and able to stream video over URL using ["Motion"](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Make-Raspberry-Pi-Webcam-Server-and-Stream-/)

Any library similar to Pi Camera or that can make me move forward from the above mentioned Motion library. would be of great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done :)

```
import pygame
import pygame.camera
import time
import base64

from googleapiclient import discovery
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials


pygame.camera.init()
pygame.camera.list_cameras()
cam = pygame.camera.Camera("/dev/video0", (640, 480))
cam.start()
time.sleep(0.1)
img = cam.get_image()
if file:
    pygame.image.save(img, file)
else:
    pygame.image.save(img, "img_captured.jpg")
cam.stop()

credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
service = discovery.build('vision', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

with open('img_captured.jpg', 'rb') as image:
    image_content = base64.b64encode(image.read())
    service_request = service.images().annotate(body={
        'requests': [{
            'image': {
                'content': image_content.decode('UTF-8')
            },
            'features': [{
                'type': 'LOGO_DETECTION',
                'maxResults': 1
            }]
        }]
    })
    response = service_request.execute()

    try:
        label = response['responses'][0]['logoAnnotations'][0]['description']
    except:
        label = "No response."

    print("Detected -->" + label)
```